# C++ WinHttpSendRequest Eror C2664

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

I am trying to make a program that takes the HTML from a website which need you to login via another site.
I am getting a problem with WinHttpSendRequest.
I expected no errors with all of them.

1. Code:

   ```
   len = (DWORD)strlen("username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=");
   bResult = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
       WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
       0,
       "username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=",
       len,
       len,
       0);
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   C2664 'BOOL' WinHttpSendRequest(HINTERNET,LPCWSTR,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD_PTR)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'const char [55]' to 'LPVOID'
   ```
2. Code:

   ```
   LPVOID data = "username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=";
   len =     (DWORD)strlen("username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=");
   bResult = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
       WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
       0,
       data,
       len,
       len,
       0);
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   C2440    'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [55]' to 'LPVOID'
   ```
3. Code:

   ```
   len = (DWORD)strlen("username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=");
   bResult = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
       WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
       0,
       (LPVOID)"username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=",
       len,
       len,
       0);
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   LNK1120 9 unresolved externals
   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpCloseHandle@4 referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl GetHTML(void)" (?GetHTML@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
   ```

   and 8 more like LNK2019 just with other

Comment: Have you tried to read e.g. [the `WinHttpSentRequest` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsendrequest)? Especially looked at the ["Requirements" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsendrequest#requirements) to see which library you need to link with?

Comment: so you need to include the Library and DLL?

Comment: The DLL should be loaded automatically, but you do need to link with the library.

Comment: it's still giving the same error after i have linked the library i have tried with `#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")` and in project settings>linker>input, and added `WinHttp.lib` to `Additional Dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

```
char    p[] = "username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=";
LPVOID  ptr = static_cast<LPVOID>( p );
int     len = strlen( p );
```

Comment: i didn't need the len, and the other code is still giving the error LNK1120 and
LNK2019

Comment: Maybe you need to clear your project, and rebuild it.